# Control history retention time length in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, history

How can I set the length of storage for history items in Google Chrome?

After having re-installed Windows 7 and all applications on my computer, I am not able to set the length of time I want it to remember in Google Chrome's history.

Have things changed (my version is v.12.0.742.112 m)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Chrome gives an option for this by default, but this extension looks like it will do what you're looking for: [History Limiter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpdjaigdefdamkfcgjhbmpjbhiejjkph)